# How to use ppx derive in utop?

Tags: ocaml, utop, ppx

How can I use ppx derive (https://github.com/ocaml-ppx/ppx_deriving) in my utop?

For example, I have to following code:

```ml
module A = struct 
  module T = struct
    type t = int [@@deriving hash, sexp, compare]
  end
  include Core_kernel.Hashable.Make(T)
end;;
```

Answer (score 4):

Simply entering:

```
#require "ppx_jane";;
```

within utop will make these macros work

Comment: `utop[18]> #require "ppx_jane";;`

`utop[19]> type abc = A | B | C [@@deriving show];;`

`Error: Ppxlib.Deriving: 'show' is not a supported type deriving generator`